# After odoo installation, either CSS nor JS are found

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

After a lot of tries, I could finally install odoo 8, however, when I connect to it, browser redirects to /web/database/manager and the HTML is loaded (the logo appears and in the title Tag appears Odoo.

The problem is that JavaScripts and CSS are not loaded (by seeing in firebug, I saw a lot of not found errors, for example, /web/static/lib/jquery.blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js)

When I see /opt/odoo/addons/web/ directory, I see that all files are there.

The strange thing is that only the company logo appears, which has this path: /web/binary/company_logo. The curious thing is that path does not actually exist physically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

EDIT:

I have enabled all log types and I see this when I start the server:

```
INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/opt/odoo/addons', '/opt/odoo/openerp/addons']
```

The path where the most pages are is actually /opt/odoo/addons, so it is correctly configured. Maybe for some reason, the path is not read.

When I see Firebug, I see this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/css/full.css"
full.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"
es5-shim.min.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js"
underscore.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/globalization/en-US.js"
en-US.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/spinjs/spin.js"
spin.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string.js"
undersc...ring.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js"
jquery.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"
jquery.blockUI.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.js"
jquery.hotkeys.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"
jquery....lder.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.js"
jquery.timeago.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.form/jquery.form.js"
jquery.form.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ba-bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.js"
jquery.ba-bbq.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/core.js"
core.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/sugarpak.js"
sugarpak.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/parser.js"
parser.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/extras.js"
extras.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.js"
jquery....date.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.autosize/jquery.autosize.js"
jquery....size.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"
jquery....-min.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js"
jquery....itor.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.textext/jquery.textext.js"
jquery.textext.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/select2/select2.js"
select2.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"
jquery-...stom.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"
jquery-...ddon.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.notify/js/jquery.notify.js"
jquery.notify.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
bootstrap.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/backbone/backbone.js"
backbone.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/qweb/qweb2.js"
qweb2.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/openerpframework.js"
openerp...work.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js"
py.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/testing.js"
testing.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/pyeval.js"
pyeval.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/core.js"
core.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/formats.js"
formats.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome.js"
chrome.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/views.js"
views.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/data.js"
data.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/data_export.js"
data_export.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/search.js"
search.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/boot.js"
boot.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_list.js"
view_list.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_form.js"
view_form.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_list_editable.js"
view_li...able.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_tree.js"
view_tree.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/base/static/src/js/apps.js"
apps.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/tour.js"
tour.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css"
font-awesome.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css"
jquery....tor.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.textext/jquery.textext.css"
jquery....ext.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/select2/select2.css"
select2.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css"
jquery-...tom.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"
jquery-...don.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.notify/css/ui.notify.css"
ui.notify.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
bootstrap.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/css/base.css"
base.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/css/data_export.css"
data_export.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/base/static/src/css/modules.css"
modules.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/globalization/en-US.js"
en-US.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/spinjs/spin.js"
spin.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js"
jquery.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"
jquery.blockUI.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.hotkeys/jquery.hotkeys.js"
jquery.hotkeys.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"
jquery....lder.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.timeago/jquery.timeago.js"
jquery.timeago.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.form/jquery.form.js"
jquery.form.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ba-bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.js"
jquery.ba-bbq.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/core.js"
core.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/parser.js"
parser.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/sugarpak.js"
sugarpak.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/datejs/extras.js"
extras.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.js"
jquery....date.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.autosize/jquery.autosize.js"
jquery....size.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"
jquery....-min.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.js"
jquery....itor.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.textext/jquery.textext.js"
jquery.textext.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/select2/select2.js"
select2.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"
jquery-...stom.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"
jquery-...ddon.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.notify/js/jquery.notify.js"
jquery.notify.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
bootstrap.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/backbone/backbone.js"
backbone.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/qweb/qweb2.js"
qweb2.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/openerpframework.js"
openerp...work.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js"
py.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/boot.js"
boot.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/testing.js"
testing.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/pyeval.js"
pyeval.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/core.js"
core.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/formats.js"
formats.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/chrome.js"
chrome.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/views.js"
views.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/data.js"
data.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/data_export.js"
data_export.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/search.js"
search.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_list.js"
view_list.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_form.js"
view_form.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_list_editable.js"
view_li...able.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/view_tree.js"
view_tree.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/base/static/src/js/apps.js"
apps.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/js/tour.js"
tour.js
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css"
font-awesome.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.textext/jquery.textext.css"
jquery....ext.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css"
jquery....tor.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/select2/select2.css"
select2.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css"
jquery-...tom.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"
jquery-...don.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/jquery.ui.notify/css/ui.notify.css"
ui.notify.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
bootstrap.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/css/base.css"
base.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/static/src/css/data_export.css"
data_export.css
"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://des.desytec.com:8069/base/static/src/css/modules.css"
modules.css
ReferenceError: $ is not defined


$(function() {
```

EDIT: I have installed nodejs and less and the same happened. This was the installation output:

```
Installed:
  nodejs.x86_64 0:0.10.35-1.el5.hg

Complete!
root@des [/usr/local/src/less-less.js-e40c2f5]# npm install -g npm
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.7.6 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
clean-css[/usr/local/src/less-less.js-e40c2f5]# npm install -g less less-plugin-
/usr/local/bin/lessc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less-plugin-clean-css@1.5.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less-plugin-clean-css
âââ clean-css@3.1.9 (commander@2.6.0, source-map@0.1.43)

less@2.5.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
âââ graceful-fs@3.0.6
âââ mime@1.3.4
âââ image-size@0.3.5
âââ promise@6.1.0 (asap@1.0.0)
âââ errno@0.1.2 (prr@0.0.0)
âââ mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
âââ source-map@0.4.2 (amdefine@0.1.0)
âââ request@2.55.0 (caseless@0.9.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.6.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, isstream@0.1.2, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.4.1, combined-stream@0.0.7, form-data@0.2.0, mime-types@2.0.10, http-signature@0.10.1, bl@0.9.4, tough-cookie@0.12.1, hawk@2.3.1, har-validator@1.6.1)
```

Comment: In `Odoo-8` there is no database selection option with login, so when you login first time it's redirect to `url/web/database/manager` or if you have created database already then `url/web/database/selector`. After selecting database you can log into the odoo system.

Comment: Maybe I could not explain myself. The problem is that  JavaScript and CSS files are not found. That is all. The problem is not about database selection or whatever occurs after the login page is loaded. Please connect to http://des.desytec.com:8069/web/database/manager and you will see the problem yourself.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

You need to install nodejs and less. How to install these depends on your operating system.
Here is an example for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

The NodeJS and NPM packages in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository can not be used because they are outdated.

Follow the instructions from the NodeJS Website:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Then install Less and accessories:

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

Comment: Thanks... I have added installation output for both nodejs and less in my question, but if you go to http://des.desytec.com:8069 the same ugly page is shown with a lot of 404 errors.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me:

Try changing the owner, group and permissions of the odoo configuration file. Odoo runs as the user "Odoo" if you follow the default configuration. But the configuration file may not be accessible to Odoo.

Try setting 
chown odoo:odoo /etc/odoo-server.conf
chmod 755 /etc/odoo-server.conf

Also, check permissions of other odoo files and addon files

Comment: When I was installing Odoo 10.0, I got same error and the cause was addon directory was not created.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same issue lately with a fresh installation and the problem was a non existing directory declared in the addons paths as stated in [this comment](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/issues/58#issuecomment-366871812). Solved by creating the directories or removing the paths from the cfg.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an internal error first then after a reload all css are missing, check your logs and fix the internal error first. I had a missing python module. I installed it and then css were back.

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with no css or js after startup on Odoo10.

See if you have symlinks in your addons path and avoid them in your command line and/or configuration file (write real path).

If you have problems with dashboard icons not showing, restart odoo with '-u all'

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is an issue with some exception.  Check the system log (for ODOO) and look for any error, especially those for the missing module.   Fix them and all resources should load correctly.